# Scan PDF files and upload it through php

Tags: php, javascript

How can I upload pdf files after scanning it through scanner feeder ? I am using [OCX](http://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/default.asp)
plugin to upload images to server, but in the application I am working on, I have to upload PDF document to server. Can you suggest me plugin or library even if is not free, I will be very thankful.

Comment: With PHP I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, how about getting the user to scan the PDF to a file and then upload the file?

Comment: @Pez Cuckow, Doesn't it the same concept of uploading images?? why it's not impossible, I make it with jpg!

Answer (score 0):

To quote my comment

> With PHP I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, how about getting the user to scan the PDF and then upload the PDF?

For example you could just get them to scan all the PDF's as `.jpeg`'s or even `.pdf`'s and then upload them as normal.

However you could look at ActiveX plugins for internet explorer that support this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45241/How-to-Scan-Tiff-and-PDF-from-the-Web

Or third party software that uploads via FTP to a web server:

http://www.z-scan2send.com/scan-to-web.html

For Chestysoft's csXImage I don't think a plugin with PDF support exists, however it can write PDF's. See http://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/manual.htm#sect1.8.9

> csXImage can save images to PDF files. The images are always saved one per page, with the page size set equal to the image size.

And further up the manual:

> The following file types are supported: .bmp, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .jpe, .png, .wbmp, .wbm, .pcx, .psd, .tif and .tiff.

Comment: I am trying the csXImage code now, I with it could work. Thanks for your care.